# Is it true that AirAsia does not allow backpacks as carry on luggage even if they fit within dimensions?

Tags: air-travel, regulations, thailand, hand-luggage, airasia

I will be flying Bangkok - Phnom Penh with AirAsia. I am used to having a backpack as hand luggage and have Osprey 40l backpack (53 x 33 x 23) that is exactly made to fit the [max hand baggage dimensions (56x36x23)](http://www.lengthytravel.com/my-latest-backpack-an-osprey-farpoint-series-review-40-55-70/#Specifications).

However I have heard anecdotally that AirAsia does not allow backpacks as hand luggage even if they fit within dimensions - which I find hard to believe.

**Is it true that AirAsia does not allow backpacks as hand luggage even if they fit within dimensions?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's what [they](http://www.airasia.com/la/en/baggage-info/cabin-baggage.page) say:

> Important notice:
>
> 1. Boxes and hiking backpacks are not considered as cabin baggage and must be checked in.
> 2. Multiple items that are strapped, wrapped or tied together will not be counted as one piece of cabin baggage.

Comment: Hi pnuts, would this Osprey count as hiking backpack you think?https://www.ospreypacks.com/us/en/product/farpoint-40-FARPNT40.html

Comment: From OP's link "The entire suspension stows away under a zippered panel creating a sleek silhouette for transport."  So the shoulder harness is not visible and you carry it by a handle.  On that basis its not a backpack when harness is stowed.   YMMV though.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've flown with a full and obviously large (50L) backpack on AirAsia a few times before and not had a problem. I suspect this not enforced except in special circumstances (like there being no room left in the cabin).

Comment: We just flew Air Asia Thailand to Hong Kong and two gals with similar looking backpacks heading to the gate area were sent back to the check in counter to check their bags by an Air Asia employee. So some staff members do enforce the rules.

Comment: @pnuts They had them over their shoulders.

Comment: Flew Bangkok - Kuala Lumpur and back again about two weeks ago - no problems whatsoever with our backpacks. They also didn't charge any fees for reprinting our boarding passes (we had checked in online, but not from the app, and didn't have time to print out the boarding passes so we just had them in our phones). It's probably worth a try, just be at the airport in time for any surprises, act clueless and see what happens...

Comment: @pnuts Many times in 2012-14, and once recently in August 2016.

Comment: @pnuts To me it sounds more like a statement that is meant to deter the usual backpacker crowd from even thinking about trying to bring their *oversized* backpacks as carry on. Who is to determine whether a backpack is a _hiking backpack_ or just a _backpack_ anyway? Is it because it has a frame? There are hard suitcases which I'm sure are allowed, and which are less compressable than a small framed backpack. Not to mention that a laptop in your backpack is essentially the same as a "frame"...

Comment: @Tom Are you sure those girls' backpacks weren't oversized or overweight?

Comment: Did they say anything about harnesses and shoulders? I only saw "hiking backpack" mentioned in their rules? To me that would indicate that any "non-hiking backpack" would be okay (I bet a random AirAsia employee and Bear Grylls would disagree on what's what tho :-). Anyway, I guess we can only speculate until someone who has actually been denied boarding with a bag on the basis that it's deemed a "hiking backpack", or an official from AirAsia, posts an answer.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Perhaps sending an inquiry to AirAsia asking for a clarification about what _they_ consider to be a hiking backpack vs. a "normal backpack" is your best bet at this point in time?

Comment: Just to confirm I did go through with my backpack no problems...

Answer (score 7):

AirAsia doesn't prohibit hiking backpacks in their [Cabin baggage](https://www.airasia.com/la/en/baggage-info/cabin-baggage.page) page anymore. So as long as your backpack fits the dimensions (56cm x 36cm x 23cm) it should be fine to bring on board.